# i want to automate the program to be infinite execution instead of work by conditions

Tags: python, selenium, artificial-intelligence

i have this automated program with python for specific hashtag for me , the code is running by specifing the number of the photos you want to like on the hashtag , i want to make the program automatically detect the new posts since added on the hashtag and like it , without clicking already liked photos ( Refactor )

this is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

class InstagramBot:
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.bot = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=('C:/chwd/chromedriver.exe'))

    def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
        time.sleep(3)
        email = bot.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
        password = bot.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(self.password + Keys.RETURN)

        time.sleep(3)

    def searchHashtag(self,hashtag):
        bot = self.bot

        bot.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' + hashtag)

    def likePhotos(self,amount):
        bot = self.bot

        bot.find_element_by_class_name('v1Nh3').click()

        i = 1
        while i <= amount:
            time.sleep(1)
            bot.find_element_by_class_name('fr66n').click()
            bot.find_element_by_class_name('coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow').click()
            time.sleep(1)

            i += 1







insta = InstagramBot('username', 'password')
insta.login()
insta.searchHashtag('likemyaccnow')
insta.likePhotos(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you want to only like pictures your program haven't seen before, you would have to remember the files you already have seen by either saving it into a json file or saving it into RAM (this resets after you restart your program). But in order to save images you have to differentiate on the photos, you could maybe look at the id of the image (if such exists) else maybe look at the date.
Happy coding

Comment: my program don't save any images , i want the bot do the following : will login automatically to my instagram account ( take the login credintials from the code ) and likes any instagram photo that contains this hashtag #likemyaccnow , i did this mentioned code , but this code will like a specified number of photos ( look at the last line in the code ) , and the code dosent identifying the already liked photos , the second running will unlike the photos ):

Comment: You don't have to save the images but just the id that Instagram assigned to it. But I don't have Instagram so I can't check it for you